# Store image to use in all resolutions

Tags: android, png, drawable

I want to use PNG image with fixed pixels on my application. **I don't want to add the same image into all folders** (ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi). Image will get blurred if I just add it into one folder. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `drawable-nodpi` directory, if I understood your intent correctly. Images in there will be displayed as is on the device, no scaling will be used. That means that it might be really small on some device and/or really large on other devices.

More info in [Table 2 here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `drawable` folder to put your PNG. To prevent from image blurring, use high resolution images(xxxhdpi), and create different layout for each dpi and set size on each image you are using. Hope this trick can help.

Answer (score 3):

Add your 640 dpi image to the drawable-xxxhdpi folder.
It will be scaled DOWN (that is, no blur due to stretch up will occur).
It's always better to scale DOWN rather than UP.